# UDF Circular reference

Tags: excel, vba, circular-reference

I have a task with creating a couple UDF's mainly to compare sales figures against a benchmark and then return an integer based on the same value which was returned on a previous sheet. I've run into a the infamous circular error which makes no sense to me because while I am referring to the address of the cell which is a no-no in VBA, it's only in the context of another sheet.

If I enable iterative calculations, it works but then on occasion the it continues to iterate and just jacks the return value up. Which affects the entire workbook. I feel like I'm missing something simple here but I lack the experience with VBA to know explicitly. If someone has a quick easy fix that I might be overlooking I'd much appreciate it.

I'm about at wits and and going to just do this in Python using xlwings or Java using Apache POI. Consider this my hail mary pass at giving up on VBA. Any ideas?

```
Function tier1(Sales As Double) As Integer
    'Constant Declaration
    'Change these to alter benchmark values
    Const BENCH As Double = 133000#
    Const VARIANCE As Double = 0.9

    'Variable Declaration
    Dim callCell As String
    Dim sheet As Integer
    Dim oldValue As Integer
    Dim returnValue As Integer

    'Assigns Values to callCell & sheet
    sheet = ActiveSheet.Index
    callCell = Application.Caller.Address

    If sheet > 1 Then
        oldValue = Worksheets(sheet - 1).Range(callCell).Value
    Else
        oldValue = 0
    End If

    Select Case Sales
        Case Is >= BENCH
            Select Case oldValue
                Case Is > 0
                    returnValue = oldValue - 1
                Case Is > 2
                    returnValue = 2
                Case Else
                    returnValue = 0
            End Select
        Case Is < BENCH
            returnValue = oldValue + 1
            If Sales > (BENCH * VARIANCE) And returnValue > 2 Then
                returnValue = 2
            End If
        End Select

        tier1 = returnValue
End Function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have to be careful when referring to other sheets within a UDF that you get the sheet you expect.  All your references should be qualified, otherwise they will default to something which might not be what you expect.

For example:

```
oldValue = Worksheets(sheet - 1).Range(callCell).Value
```

is the same as:

```
oldValue = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(sheet - 1).Range(callCell).Value
```

so if the workbook containing your formula isn't the active workbook, your results are likely to not be what you expect.

A few suggested edits:

```
Function tier1(Sales As Double) As Integer
    'Constant Declaration
    'Change these to alter benchmark values
    Const BENCH As Double = 133000#
    Const VARIANCE As Double = 0.9

    'Variable Declaration
    Dim callCell As Range
    Dim sheet As Integer
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim oldValue As Integer
    Dim returnValue As Integer

    Set callCell = Application.Caller
    Set wb = callCell.Worksheet.Parent
    sheet = callCell.Worksheet.Index

    If sheet > 1 Then
        oldValue = wb.Worksheets(sheet - 1).Range(callCell.Address).Value
    Else
        oldValue = 0
    End If

    Select Case Sales
        Case Is >= BENCH
            Select Case oldValue
                Case Is > 0
                    returnValue = oldValue - 1
                Case Is > 2
                    returnValue = 2
                Case Else
                    returnValue = 0
            End Select
        Case Is < BENCH
            returnValue = oldValue + 1
            If Sales > (BENCH * VARIANCE) And returnValue > 2 Then
                returnValue = 2
            End If
        End Select

        tier1 = returnValue
End Function
```

Comment: Thank you for that Tim, I would have never thought of that. VBA seems a little like voodoo to me. Hopefully if they need a more in depth solution I'll be able to talk them into something better.